# Separating different kinds of footnotes with bigfoot

Tags: footnotes, rules, bigfoot

I am using the bigfoot package to create two sets of footnotes, one in para style and the other plain (in that order on the page). I have removed the line separating these footnotes from the body of the text using `\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}`, but I *would* like a line to appear between the two types of footnotes to produce an effect similar to the document below, with the alphabetical (paragraph) footnotes beneath the text body and the numerical (plain) ones below a line. What would be the simplest way to do this? (I can provide more information about my current setup if necessary, but I'm new to asking questions and didn't know what to include. Thanks!)

[image]

Comment: Neat idea... now help the community to get started by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your input, perhaps with undesired output.

Comment: Werner is correct that normally questioners should provide a MWE to increase the chance of helpful answers. In your case, I can provide an answer on top of my head. Should my answer fail to work for you (because of conflicting packages and/or classes), please add a MWE when editing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bigfoot` documentation is rather short; however, it states in the last-but-one paragraph:

> [F]or the customization possibilities of `bigfoot` with regards to
>   multiple footnote blocks and rules between them, refer to `manyfoot`’s
>   documentation.

The `manyfoot` package includes the `\extrafootnoterule` macro which controls the rule between different footnote blocks and is empty by default. In your case, copy the original definition of `\footnoterule` to `\extrafootnoterule` and only then redefine `\footnoterule`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}[alph]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnote}
\DeclareNewFootnote{L}
\MakeSorted{footnoteL}

\let\extrafootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\footnote{A para footnote.}

Some more text.\footnote{Another para footnote.}

And some more.\footnoteL{A plain footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image]